# Core data save error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an viewController, which inserts new Core data objects. my problem is, that I get the following error in my save function:

```
[Messdiener_Memory.Spiel managedObjectModel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fddebf7e220'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103e20d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001064cddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103e29d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d6fcfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d6f8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010397a4f3 -[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 83
    6   Messdiener-Memory                   0x0000000103818d7c _TFC17Messdiener_Memory6PersoncfT6entityCSo19NSEntityDescription30insertIntoManagedObjectContextGSqCSo22NSManagedObjectContext__S0_ + 76
    7   Messdiener-Memory                   0x000000010384b466 _TFC17Messdiener_Memory20NeuesSpielController19fertigButtonPressedfCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 3542
    8   Messdiener-Memory                   0x000000010384b98a _TToFC17Messdiener_Memory20NeuesSpielController19fertigButtonPressedfCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104f53a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000105361067 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104f53a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001050c6e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001050c7143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001050c72be -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 706
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001050c6263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104fc699f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104fc76d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104f72dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104f4c553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d46301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d3c22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d3b6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d3b0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010957ead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000104f51f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  Messdiener-Memory                   0x0000000103842502 main + 114
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106f9a92d start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Everything I know is that the error has to be after the line    spiel!.personen = NSSet(array: temp) and the error in catch is not printed.

```
 spiel!.gruppen = NSOrderedSet(array: gruppen)

    spiel!.personen = NSSet(array: temp)
    spiel?.maxPunkte = gesamtPunkte


    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        print("YES")
        app?.aktivesSpiel(spiel)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try adding an exception-breakpoint. It will tell you exactly on which line it fails

Comment: @TMob I've done it and it fails at try managedContext.save() but I really don't know why

Comment: Where are you calling insert into context?

Comment: Where is your `managedContext ` defined? It doesn't seem to be that what is it supposed to then